# How to get today's date with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, datetime

I have a python script that imports a df, processes it, and then outputs to a csv file.  I'm using `pandas.write_csv()` to output the file.

I'm looking to standardize the manner in which my script names the output file.  Specifically, I would like for the script to pull today's date as format: MMDDYYYY and insert that to the end of the CSV file.

```
outputfile = 'mypotentialfilename_MMDDYYYY.csv'
pd.write_csv(outputfile)
```

In the past, I've seen quick ways to insert a date into a text, but I cannot seem to find the code to review.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to remember: **strptime** to read strings to datetime and **strftime** to print datetime strings and you just look it up. I constantly have to look up all the format options. For instance "%A" returns weekday in text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this with `dt.today` and `dt.strftime`:

```
import datetime as dt

today = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%m%d%Y')  
output_file = 'filename_{}.csv'.format(today)
```

Also, `pd.write_csv` is deprecated/removed in newer versions. I suggest upgrading your pandas to the latest version (v0.20 as of now), and using `df.to_csv`.

Comment: Perfect.  My pandas actually utilizes `.to_csv` in typing up this example quickly I resorted to old habits.  Thanks for the prompt help!

Answer (score 17):

python's `format` can handle date input

```
today = pd.Timestamp('today')
'filename_{:%m%d%Y}.csv'.format(today)

'filename_10042017.csv'
```

Using Python 3.6's `f-strings`

```
today = pd.Timestamp('today')
f'filename_{today:%m%d%Y}.csv'

'filename_10042017.csv'
```

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. Wonderful.

Comment: I found that we could also use `now = pd.to_datetime('today')` to get the same effect. `pd.Timestamp` was new for me. But, I keep using `to_datetime` a lot. So, this was easier for me to remember.